# Why is the reentrant random generator rand_r() considered weak?

Tags: c, random

The man page for `rand_r()` states:

> The  value  pointed to by the seedp argument of rand_r() provides only a very small amount of state, so this function will be a weak pseudo-random generator.

Could someone explain what this sentence means? How is it that the seed value "provides only a very small amount of state", and how does that weaken the generator?

Before I start using the GNU extension `drand48_r()` as a better alternative, I want to be sure I am making an informed choice. Perhaps for some use cases `rand_r()` is sufficient, otherwise there would be no sense in it being available.

**EDIT** in response to comments:

I wish to better undestand the functions and the way they are explained, preferrably without reference to a particular use case that could constrain the explanation. There are plenty of use cases discussed on the net, but general knowledge about the functions is either lacking or difficult to understand. SO has in the past been great with Q&A introductions, hence my question.

If it helps, I have done a test to compare `rand()` and `rand_r()`, producing two random RGB images, where the pixels were generated with:

```
pxsPtr[i] = (uint8_t) rand() % 255; // rand() version

pxsPtr[i] = (uint8_t) rand_r(&randRseed) % 255; // rand_r() version
```

I'm surprised by their similarity and now even more eager to obtain answers to my questions.

[image: rand() test]

[image: rand_r() test]

Comment: `seedp` is pointer to unsigned int, so (on a typical system) there are at most 32 bits of state.

Comment: List some example of your use cases.  If they include randomizing to generate broad band randomness, with no bias, then `rand()`, `rand_r()`, etc will not work for you, otherwise they are fine. Here are some related links on the topic: [ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775578/biased-random-number-generator), [ref2](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Unbias_a_random_generator), [ref3](https://zuttobenkyou.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/generating-random-numbers-without-modulo-bias/)

Comment: What are you using the generator for?

Comment: Neither is a very good random number generator; they're both unsuitable anywhere you need unpredictability. You should clarify what you actually want to get out of this question.

Comment: To all commenters - please see my edit to the question.

Comment: `general knowledge about the functions` [rand_r()](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/rand_r.c#L27) is really simple function.