# Rand function, generate probability across 3 values (for simple slot machine)?

Tags: c++, random, probability

I am making a simple (terminal) slot machine project, in which 3 fruit names will be output in the terminal, and if they are all the same then the player wins.

I cannot figure out how to make a set probability that the player will win the round (roughly 40% chance for example). As of now I have:

```
     this->slotOne = rand() % 6 + 1;              // chooses rand number for designated slot
     this->oneFruit = spinTOfruit(this->slotOne); //converts rand number to fruit name

     this->slotTwo = rand() % 6 + 1;
     this->twoFruit = spinTOfruit(this->slotTwo);

     this->slotThree = rand() % 6 + 1;
     this->threeFruit = spinTOfruit(this->slotThree);
```

which picks a "fruit" based on the number, but each of the three slots has a 1 in 6 chance (seeing that there are 6 fruits). Since each individual slot has a 1/6 chance, overall the probability of winning is incredibly low.

How would I fix this to create better odds (or even better, chosen odds, changing the odds when desired)?

I thought of changing the second two spins to less options (rand()%2 for instance), but that would make the last two slots choose the same couple fruits every time.

The link to my project: https://github.com/tristanzickovich/slotmachine

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649717/c-function-for-picking-from-a-list-where-each-element-has-a-distinct-probabili?rq=1) for some inspiration.

Comment: I think it's 1/36 %. The first spin is independent. The next two are dependent. 6/6*1/6*1/6=1/36.  Which is still a mere 2.77 percent

Comment: @TristanZickovich: On a slot machine, how is the 2nd wheel dependent on the first?

Comment: But the first spin can be anything. Then the next two have to be the same, so only the second two have 1/6, right?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: it's dependent if you're looking for a matching number.  Depending on what you get for the first, the second and third must follow to be a winner

Comment: In a 3 wheel slot machine, the wheels are independent of each other.  This allows each wheel to display the same value, which ends up in a win.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cheat.

Decide **first** if the player wins or not

```
const bool winner = ( rand() % 100 ) < 40 // 40 % odds (roughly)
```

**Then** invent an outcome that supports your decision.

```
if ( winner )
{
   // Pick the one winning fruit.
   this->slotOne = this->slotTwo = this->slotThree = rand() % 6 + 1;  
}
else
{
   // Pick a failing combo.
   do
   {
        this->slotOne = rand() % 6 + 1;    
        this->slotTwo = rand() % 6 + 1;    
        this->slotThree = rand() % 6 + 1;    
   } while ( slotOne == slotTwo && slotTwo == slotThree );
}
```

You can now toy with the player's emotions like the Vegas best.