# How to pick a number based on probability?

Tags: algorithm, math, probability

I want to select a random number from `0,1,2,3...n`, however I want to make it that the chance of selecting `k|0<k<n` will be lower by multiplication of `x` from selecting `k - 1` so `x = (k - 1) / k`. As bigger the number as smaller the chances to pick it up.

As an answer I want to see the implementation of the next method:

```
int pickANumber(n,x)
```

This is for a game that I am developing, I saw those questions as related but not exactly that same:

- [How to pick an item by its probability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330394/how-to-pick-an-item-by-its-probability)
- [C Function for picking from a list where each element has a distinct probabili](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649717/c-function-for-picking-from-a-list-where-each-element-has-a-distinct-probabili)

Comment: I think you mean "k | 0 <= k <= n". (Deleted rest of comment, which was wrong.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker yeah, tnx

Comment: Wow, this is really unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p1 + p2 + ... + pn = 1
p1 = p2 * x
p2 = p3 * x
...
p_n-1 = pn * x
```

Solving this gives you:

```
p1 + p2 + ... + pn = 1
(p2 * x) + (p3 * x) + ... + (pn * x) + pn = 1
((p3*x) * x) + ((p4*x) * x) + ... + ((p_n-1*x) * x) + pn = 1
....
pn* (x^(n-1) + x^(n-2) + ... +x^1 + x^0) = 1
pn*(1-x^n)/(1-x) = 1
pn = (1-x)/(1-x^n)
```

This gives you the probability you need to set to `pn`, and from it you can calculate the probabilities for all other p1,p2,...p_n-1

Now, you can use a "black box" RNG that chooses a number with a distribution, like those in the threads you mentioned.

A simple approach to do it is to set an auxillary array:

```
aux[i] = p1 + p2 + ... + pi
```

Now, draw a random number with uniform distribution between `0` to `aux[n]`, and using binary search (aux array is sorted), get the first value, which matching value in `aux` is greater than the random uniform number you got

---

Original answer, for substraction (before question was editted):

For `n` items, you need to solve the equation:

```
p1 + p2 + ... + pn = 1
p1 = p2 + x
p2 = p3 + x
...
p_n-1 = pn + x
```

Solving this gives you:

```
p1 + p2 + ... + pn = 1
(p2 + x) + (p3 + x) + ... + (pn + x) + pn = 1
((p3+x) + x) + ((p4+x) + x) + ... + ((p_n-1+x) + x) + pn = 1
....
pn* ((n-1)x + (n-2)x + ... +x + 0) = 1
pn* x = n(n-1)/2
pn = n(n-1)/(2x)
```

This gives you the probability you need to set to `pn`, and from it you can calculate the probabilities for all other p1,p2,...p_n-1

Now, you can use a "black box" RNG that chooses a number with a distribution, like those in the threads you mentioned.

---

Be advised, this is not guaranteed you will have a solution such that `0<p_i<1` for all `i`, but you cannot guarantee one given from your requirements, and it is going to depend on values of `n` and `x` to fit.

Comment: Its not p1 = p2 + x but p1 = p2 * x, its my mistake in the description of the question. I ment lawer by multiplication. Sorry

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman Your question says "Lower by x", which means substraction, not division. Anyway, it can be done very similarly for division - but using geometric series for the summation rather than an arithmetic progression, and getting the formula

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman I added a solution for multiplication, it's the same principle. You might also look at exponential distribution, which is a close variant, though a continious one.

Comment: [it's not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699503/how-to-control-the-probability-of-picking-a-number)

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman As for the additive solution (substracting, not dividing), note what I explicitly wrote - it will not work for some values, because it might result in negative values of some `pi`, or values greater than 1. There is nothing you can do about it without relaxing the requirements, since this is the answer for solving `n` linear formulas with `n` variables, and there is a single solution to it

Comment: I didn't say that your solution is not working, I think that my idea with my requirements did not work for what I actually need. The way that I picked up a number some how canceled the values of X. Check out the solution that I received for the second question, I think that it exactly the relaxing of the requirements that I been searching for, It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** This answer was for the OPs original question, which was different in that each probability was supposed to be lower by a fixed amount than the previous one.

Well, let's see what the constraints say. You want to have *P(k) = P(k - 1) - x*. So we have:

*P(0)*

*P(1) = P(0) - x*

*P(2) = P(0) - 2x*
...

In addition, *Sum<sub>k</sub> P(k) = 1*. Summing, we get:

1 = (n + 1)P(0) -x * n / 2 (n + 1),

This gives you an easy constraint between *x* and *P(0)*. Solve for one in terms of the other.

Answer (score 0):

For this I would use the Mersenne Twister algorithm for a uniform distribution which Boost provides, then have a mapping function to map the results of that random distribution to the actual number select.

Here's a quick example of a potential implementation, although I left out the quadtratic equation implementation since it is well known:

```
int f_of_xib(int x, int i, int b)
{
    return x * i * i / 2 + b * i;
}

int b_of_x(int i, int x)
{
    return (r - ( r ) / 2 );
}


int pickANumber(mt19937 gen, int n, int x)
{
    // First, determine the range r required where the probability equals i * x
    // since probability of each increasing integer is x higher of occuring.
    // Let f(i) = r and given f'(i) = x * i then r = ( x * i ^2 ) / 2 + b * i
    // where b = ( r - ( x * i ^ 2 ) / 2 ) / i . Since r = x when i = 1 from problem
    // definition, this reduces down to b = r - r / 2. therefore to find r_max simply
    // plugin x to find b, then plugin n for i, x, and b to get r_max since r_max occurs
    // when n == i.

    // Find b when 
    int b = b_of_x(x);
    int r_max = f_of_xib(x, n, b);

    boost::uniform_int<> range(0, r_max);
    boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::uniform_int<> > next(gen, range);

    // Now to map random number to desired number, just find the positive value for i
    // when r is the return random number which boils down to finding the non-zero root
    // when 0 = ( x * i ^ 2 ) / 2 + b * i - r
    int random_number = next();

    return quadtratic_equation_for_positive_value(1, b, r);
}



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    mt19937 gen;
    gen.seed(time(0));

    pickANumber(gen, 10, 1);

    system("pause");
}
```