# Choosing random event with different probabilities

Tags: c++, events, probability

I need help creating a general function or pseudocode that chooses a single event from a group events who all have different probabilities.
Ex.

- event 1 = 45%
- event 2 = 15%
- event 3 = 50%
- event 4 = 35%
- event 5 = 50%

Comment: What does the C++ tag stand for?

Comment: I will be coding in c++

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ function for picking from a list where each element has a distinct probability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649717/c-function-for-picking-from-a-list-where-each-element-has-a-distinct-probabili)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to sum and normalize the ranges (as an example, the sum of the values is 195, your first event would get the range [0, 45/195=0.23[, the second one [0.23, 0.23+0.076=0.31], and so on), then extract a number from [0,1[ and look to what range it belongs.